# pandas dataframe select list value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Everyone! I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
        A       B
   0    [1,2,3] 0
   1    [2,3,4] 1
```

as we can see, the A column is a list and the B column is an index value. I want to get a C column which is index by B from A:

```
        A       B     C
   0    [1,2,3] 0     1
   1    [2,3,4] 1     3
```

Is there any elegant method to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension with indexing:

```
df['C'] = [x[y] for x, y in df[['A','B']].to_numpy()]
```

Or [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), but it should be slowier if large DataFrame:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.A[x.B], axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
           A  B  C
0  [1, 2, 3]  0  1
1  [2, 3, 4]  1  3
```